# how to looping data laravel in jstree

Tags: php, laravel, jstree

code in my controller

```
public function see($users_parent_id)
{
  $data['data'] = Downline::where('users_parent_id',$users_parent_id)->first();
  $data['data2'] = Downline::where('users_parent_id',$users_parent_id)->get();
  $data['data3'] = Downline::where('users_parent_id',$data['data']->users_id)->get();
  $data['users'] = User::where('role','member')->get();

  return view('backend.pages.downline.show', $data);
}
```

and my looping data in jstree

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var arrayCollection = [
    {"id": "{{ $data->users_parent_id }}", "parent": "#", "text": "{{ $data->users_parent->fullname }}"},
    @foreach($data2 as $item2)
      {"id": "{{ $item2->users_id }}", "parent": "{{ $data->users_parent_id }}", "text": "{{ $item2->users->fullname }}"},
    @endforeach
    @foreach($data3 as $item3)
      {"id": "{{ $item3->users_id }}", "parent": "{{ $item3->users_parent_id }}", "text": "{{ $item3->users->fullname }}"},
    @endforeach
  ];

  $('#container').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': arrayCollection
    }
  });
});
```

my question:
how to looping laravel data in jstree without using a lot of foreach?

Comment: create a function in your controller that does what you're doing in the view, then pass that end result to your view, so you could just use it immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an associative array with `array_map` and then use laravel helper function `json()` to pass it to the view.